# Regular Expression to Match HTML <p> tag using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some content like this

```
<p>some content, paragraph 1</p>
<p>some content, paragraph 2</p>
<p>some content, paragraph 3</p>
```

I would like to return the first paragraph i.e.

```
<p>some content, paragraph 1</p>
```

Can anyone assist me with the regex code?
`'<p>(.*.)</p>'` doesnt seem to work

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
if (preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

You test your string against the regular expresion, if there are some match, you get the first and only the first one, if there are none $result will be an empty string.

If you need to get more than the first result you can iterate over the $regs array. And of you need to find any other tag change the regular expresión to macht it, for example to find IMAGE tags you use:

```
(<img[^>]*>.*?</img>)
```

**EDIT:** If you are processing line by line (with only the tag you are looking for) you can put ^...$ around the expresion to match a full line, like this:

```
if (preg_match('%^(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)$%im', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

HTH, Regards.

Comment: Hi, how you can do with a "for" (loop) ? character by character ? for( $i = 0; $i <= $strlen; $i++ ) {if($cadena{$i}=="<"){NOT WORKS}}

Answer (score 5):

Prevent from include <pre> tag, can use:

```
if (preg_match('/(<p(>|\s+[^>]*>).*?<\/p>)/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  if (preg_match("/\b1\b/i", "some content, paragraph 1")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Where 1 is the matched term...

Is this is any help?