# How to test if a HTML body contains empty tags

Tags: php, tinymce

I am using a text editor on certain form fields, **TinyMCE**. it works ok.

However the TinyMCE editor returns a HTML body tag for each field in the form. This is perfectly fine if a user completes that form field, i.e;

```
'description' => string '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    a users response
    </body>
    </html>'
```

However, if a user does not complete the field TinyMCE STILL returns a string containing an empty html body, i.e the code below:

```
 'description' => string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>'
```

What I want to do is to test if this returned 'form field' contains just empty HTML field, i.e no values within the body of the html field.

In summary how can I test that the above code just contains empty body tags?

Comment: By "tinymice" you mean "tinymce" right?

Comment: Hi Juhana. yes. that is exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not a very ellegant solution but it works. i simply remove the tags from the document using the strip_tag(), then test if the variable is empty. If its not empty i submit the post variable.

```
if (isset($_POST['description']))
                {
                    $preValidated = dsf_db_prepare_input($_POST['description']);
                    $testValue  = trim(strip_tags($preValidated));

                    if(!strlen($testValue) >= 1)
                    {
                        $description ='';
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $description ="$preValidated";
                     }     
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it on the client side using jquery

```
if($('<html><body></body></html>').find('body').children().length < 1) {
  console.log('empty')
} else {
  console.log('not empty');
}
```

you can validate and send appropriate response to the server

Comment: Thanks reverbnation, but i want to keep the validation within php

Comment: @PaulKendal take a look at this you can easily do it using preg_match http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264678/regular-expression-to-match-html-p-tag-using-php