# How to make Tiny MCE return empty string if textarea is left blank

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce

I am currently using Tiny MCE in one of my forms to enter information into a MySQL database and the textarea, replaced by the TinyMCE plugin, is optional so if the user doesnt have to fill it.

But checking the POST data sent, the textarea variable has default HTML tags, how can I configure Tiny MCE to return nothing if the textarea is left blank.

Thanks

Comment: Why? What your Tiny MCE returns after submit the form if it's empty?

Comment: It returns doctype html head and body tags

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512309/how-to-test-if-a-html-body-contains-empty-tags